# Jest failing tests on same objects

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

One of my unit tests fail with output like the below

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

- Expected
+ Received

- {"cartId": "_id_", "devices": [{"foo": "bar"}], "language": "_language_", "province": "_province_"},
+ {"cartId": "_id_", "devices": [{"foo": "bar"}], "language": "_language_", "province": "_province_"},
```

for line

```
 expect(mockTransformer).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...
```

The question is, if expected and received are same, how can this tests fail?

Here is the test code in picture:

```
   expect(mytestingfunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      devices: [{ foo: 'bar' }],
      cartId: '_id_',
      language: '_language_',
      province: '_province_'
    })
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: just added the code

Comment: Please post the code you want to test. I made a simple demo, it works fine.

Comment: can you share your demo on some online code runner please? I have added the code as you requested.